# Should I change my question when a better approach has been proposed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I [made a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675379/specialise-functor-when-template-class-is-convertible-to-a-well-known-type) asking about doing something with boost and one person gave a solution using boost. Later, another person answered about using just standard C++ and I really think that approach is better just because it's standard.

At first, I thought of not changing the question and accepted answer because I already had talked about using boost and that would be a little unfair, but, what do you think about this? should I change my question / question tags and accepted answer to provide a more standard approach to the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you should not change your question into something different once answers have been provided.

Remember that your post should have value for future visitors. Somewhere, someday, somebody concludes that using boost would be great! After a search that somebody finds your question, and in all the excitement up votes your question. After reading the answers they conclude the same thing you do: *Meh, standard C++ is better*.

Questions never tend to be wrong (a lot of them are low quality/badly researched/lack any effort but that is different story) but some answers can amaze you and that is where you learned something as well as future visitors who start out on the same hypotheses.

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it while I was still writing.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm so sorry. Just ping me in the chatroom if I should leave a question alone...